# How to generate a new column which is a range based on other 2 columns in SQL lite

Tags: sql, sqlite

Hi i have a table looks like this and I want to get all the months the customers are active

| Customer ID | Start | End |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | 2020-10-01 | 2020-12-10 |
| B | 2020-08-01 | 2020-10-30 |
| c | 2020-12-01 | 'None' |

The output table should be something like this

| Customer ID | active_month |
| --- | --- |
| A | 10 |
| A | 11 |
| A | 12 |
| B | 8 |
| B | 9 |
| B | 10 |
| c | 12 |

Is there any simple way to do this in SQLlite? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```sql
WITH RECURSIVE
cte(CustomerID, active_month, End) AS 
       ( SELECT CustomerID, strftime('%m', Start) + 0, strftime('%m', End) + 0
         FROM customer
         UNION ALL
         SELECT CustomerID, active_month + 1, End 
         FROM cte
         WHERE active_month < End )
SELECT CustomerID, active_month
FROM cte
ORDER BY CustomerID, active_month;
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.27&fiddle=9a5f7c522497890eb0a7110b2ebcdf89)

Both dates in source row **must** have the same year part.

Comment: Thank you! But i also have an issue where the end date might be 'None' Do you know what is the best way to do the similar thing?

Comment: *the end date might be 'None'* Use `COALESCE(strftime('%m', End) + 0, 12)` in CTE (if 'None' means NULL). Or use CASE function.